# Does any Spider-Man villain other than Dr. Octopus and the Lizard have a PhD?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

I am particularly curious about Norman Osborn.

Any universe is fine, as long as you state about which universe you are answering for.

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Doctors

Comment: Vulture was engineer, but I don't reckon if he had Phd.

Comment: The Lizard doesn't have a PhD, but his alter-ego does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Norman Osborn in the Ultimate Universe (1610) is listed as having a "PhD in various sciences" on [Marvel's own site](https://www.marvel.com/characters/green-goblin-ultimate). He is certainly portrayed as having a direct hand in the Oz Formula that causes both his and Spider-Man's powers, although still seems to be portrayed mostly as an industrialist/CEO rather than as a scientist.

Answer (score 10):

[Jackal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackal_(Marvel_Comics_character)), the Spider-Man villain behind the notorious "Clone Saga," was a professor of biochemistry and has a PhD according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

There is [Professor Smythe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_Smythe), the robotics and arachnid physiology expert, who built the "spider slayer" robots to hunt Spider-Man (including one that was large for him to ride inside it and pilot it).  He first appeared in The *Amazing Spider-Man* no. 25, and he usually worked in collaboration with J. Jonah Jameson, up through his death in issue no. 191.

Comment: Do we know he had a PhD? There are lots of “Doctors” and “Professors” in Marvel and comics in general that don’t actually have one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot What notable "Doctors" and "Professors" in Marvel _don't_ have PhDs? (Excluding the Dr. Stark, which is not a common title)

Comment: @Logarr Dr Lorina Dodson aka the White Rabbit is one example off of the top of my head.

Comment: @Logarr - I think Doctor Doom is another. Near as I can tell Victor Von Doom dropped out of college.

Comment: @T.E.D. If Doom's country has a college then he can award himself that title.  I seriously doubt his ego would let him have less of a title than Richards so he's presumably done something.

Comment: @DarkMatter That would be an honorary doctorate though.  Presumably the question is only about individuals with *earned* doctorates.

Comment: @Buzz An "honorary" doctorate for someone with absurdly great achievements in engineering and science.  One way or another he's earned the title.